# How to unit test Spring Security default POST "/login"

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, spring-security, mocking

I have implemented a login process using spring-security default POST /login.
I have added configuration to return a JWT token in the header if the response is successful.
This is working fine but I now have to write unit tests for each of my Controller's and endpoints.
I am having problems testing this with MockMVC and cannot find a way around it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Note:
I have tried https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

Login Unit test

```
    @Test
    public void login() throws Exception{

        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
        user.setUsername("user");
        user.setPassword("password");

        String uri = "/login";
        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(uri)
                .content(mapToJson(user))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();

        int statusCode = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();

        assertEquals(200, statusCode);
        assert(mvcResult.getResponse().containsHeader("Authentication"));
    }
```

Error im getting

```
rg.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SecureApp.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SecureApp.SecureAppApplicationTests.login(SecureAppApplicationTests.java:83) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:na]
```

Abstract Setup for tests

```
public class Abstract {

    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    protected void setUp(){
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();

    }

    protected String mapToJson(Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    }

    protected <T> T mapFromJson(String jsonAsString, Class<T> absClass) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(jsonAsString, absClass);
    }

}
```

Security Class's

JWTAuthentication Filter

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);




    }
```

JWTAuthorizationFilter

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers","Origin","Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT"));
        corsConfiguration.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
        corsConfiguration.addExposedHeader("Message");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/activities/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/home/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }


    }
```

Comment: Do you want to just test your controller? Or do you want a full integration test?

Comment: I didnt write a function to handle /login in my controller. Spring security automatically includes it if you use the dependency. I want a integration test to show that it returns the token in the header